# Intercept $http request and return hardcoded data

Tags: angularjs

I would like to intercept all `$http` calls made by various services and return an object which is declared inside the interceptor a.k.a. hardcoded data.

The request interceptor provided by Angular seems to only be able to change and return the HTTP config object.

How can I manipulate the data returned without actually calling a server?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend ? Also, Lineman http://www.linemanjs.com/ has an API stubbing option that could achieve something similar

Comment: I'm not trying to test it. It's for a different purpose.

Comment: Can `$httpBackend` be switched on and off at runtime?

Comment: you can just remove the module that includes $httpBackend from your runtime build and then all the $http requests will be handled normally

Comment: Interesting. So, I'm trying to make AJAX calls to a server - works. However, after a switch is flipped I want all those calls to return hardcoded data from a central position like an HTTP interceptor without actually making a call. Can $httpBackend do that? Can you show me how, because I can't find how that would work.

Answer (score 0):

To use $httpBackend from MockE2E to provide mock API responses, either for testing purposes, or to provide a mock API to develop the client against if the server API is not available, firstly you need to include angular-mocks.js as this contains ngMockE2E.

Then you need to add a module something like:

```
angular.module('mockBackend', [ 'ngMockE2E'])
    .run(function($httpBackend) {
        phones = [{name: 'phone1'}, {name: 'phone2'}];

        // returns the current list of phones
        $httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(phones);

        // adds a new phone to the phones array
        $httpBackend.whenPOST('/phones').respond(function(method, url, data) {
        var phone = angular.fromJson(data);
        phones.push(phone);
        return [200, phone, {}];
    });
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/^\/templates\//).passThrough();
    //...
});
```

The above is taken from the docs at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMockE2E/service/$httpBackend - you would need to set up in here all your API endpoints that you want to return mock data for, along with any that you want real data for, eg. in the above any requests for 'templates' uses .passThrough to still forward these requests to the server, but returns mock data for API calls to '/phones'.

As far as how to turn this off and on goes it will depend on how you have your angular build process set up. If you do not want any of this in your production version you could put the above in a separate mockbackend.js file and add

```
angular.module('myApp').requires.push('mockBackend');
```

to the bottom of the file - where 'myApp' would be your app module. For your production files you can then have your build process (manual or automated) remove the angular-mocks.js and mockbackend.js requires from your index.html file and all your api calls will revert to calling the server.

If you wanted to vary if the mock backend is used or not during development you could pass a constant into the mockBackend module and use this to decided if real or mock data is returned, eg. if you have a constant 'DEV' which is a simple boolean:

```
if (DEV === true) {
    $httpBackend.whenGET('/phones').respond(phones);
} else {
    $httpBackend.whenGET(/phones).passThrough();
}
```